# change in old UI to new one for clear info dm @_iammainu_

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

forrrr theeee codeeee pleaasseeee dm meeee

this is the code and i want to change the UI , where the container will only carry the image icon and the name  and the phone icon . and when the container is tapped it will show the location name , hospital name, nearest hospital ...... (in the code) please help _ ig. @_iammainu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVDdC.jpg)  this is how it should look like . when tapped .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4tnA.jpg) this is when user does not tap "Director".